# Formatting Excel table using Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, excel

I am trying to come up with a way to export an attribute table as a formatted excel table in ArcMap 10.2. I am aware that there is a Table To Excel tool in the conversion toolbox, but I am not sure if there is more functionality with Excel that can be accessed using Python.

Right now I have a macro in Excel that reads in another Excel table and sorts and formats it, but I would like to be able to do this all in one moodel or script within the ArcGIS Desktop environment.

The first screenshot is the exported excel table and the second is the formatted table after running the macro.

[image: This is the table that gets exported to excel.]

[image: And here is the formatted table after running the macro]

Comment: Could you provide more details, esp. on what you want to format? Screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

There are many Python modules you can use for manipulating Excel sheets:

[xlutils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils); [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt); [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/); [xlrd](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.htm)

You could use any of those that allow modifications on Excel sheet; developing this piece of code is not dependent on ArcGIS in any way.

When you have a chunk of code that does the work for you, you can wrap it to a custom [Python script tool (or a Python toolbox)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000002r000000), expose some parameters and use it as a tool in a larger model or another custom Python script tool (or a Python toolbox).